# Laravel recursive whereHas on BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `User` which has a BelongsToMany relationship on it called `lineManagers()`. This relationship returns a collection of `User` models. The nature of this setup allows for a parent-child style relationship to operate on multiple levels.

The BelongsToMany uses a table called `line_manager_user` which has a simple schema of mapping a user id to a line manager user id:

```
| user_id | line_manager_id |
```

```
User A -> lineManagers()-> User B
                           User C -> lineManagers() -> User D
```

Depending upon certain permissions, I want to be able to query this relationship to multiple levels for users who have a line manager with a specific `users.id`, potentially using a `whereHas()` but I'm aware that this could be quite a detriment to performance.

I had tried the below query but to no avail (the last section is the relevant part):

```
$query = User::query()
    ->with('lineManagers')
    ->orderBy('first_name')
    ->orderBy('last_name')
    ->havingEmploymentStatus(UserEmploymentStatus::EMPLOYED)
    ->whereHas('lineManagers.lineManagers.lineManagers', function (Builder $query) {
        $query->where('id', $this->getAuthenticatedUser()->id);
    });
```

I don't specifically want 3 levels, ideally the query would retrieve `lineManagers` until an empty collection is hit. This does need to be something that I done at query level rather than collection level unfortunately

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correct. But for me it sounds like you have to query the line manager user table and then join the information you need: `LineManagerUser::where('user_id', $this->getAuthenticatedUser()->id)->join(User::class, 'user.id','=','line_manager_user.user_id')->get()`

Answer (score 0):

If you made it a function that called itself until it drilled down to the empty collection you could do it.  That wouldn't matter how many levels there are then

Check out https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-blade-recursive-partials/

I wouldn't recommend doing it in the blade file, rather work their "Plain old PHP" code into a function